# SQLAlchemy Joinedload filter column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi I would like to do a filter with my query using a joinedload. But I can't seem to make it work. Below is my sample query

```
result = (
        session.query(Work).
        options(
            joinedload(Work.company_users).
            joinedload(CompanyUser.user)
        ).
        filter(Work.id == 1).
        filter(User.first_name == 'The name').  <<--- I can't get this to work.
        all()
    )
```

When running this it's returning a row that is more than what I'm expecting. The real result should only return 8rows. But upon executing this query it returns 234 rows which is way more than what I expect

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that `joinedload` (and all the other relationship loading techniques) are meant to be entirely transparent. That is to say having a `joinedload` in your query should not affect it in any other way other than resulting in the relationships being filled. You should read ["The Zen of Joined Eager Loading"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading), which begins with:

> Since joined eager loading seems to have many resemblances to the use of `Query.join()`, it often produces confusion as to when and how it should be used. It is critical to understand the distinction that while `Query.join()` is used to alter the results of a query, `joinedload()` goes through great lengths to not alter the results of the query, and instead hide the effects of the rendered join to only allow for related objects to be present.

One of the tricks is to use aliases for the joined tables which are not made available. Your query then ends up performing an implicit cross-join between Work and User, and hence the extra rows. So in order to filter against a joined table, use [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join):

```
session.query(Work).\
    join(Work.company_users).\
    join(CompanyUser.user).\
    filter(Work.id == 1).\
    filter(User.first_name == 'The name').\
    all()
```

and if you also need the eagerloads in place, you can instruct the Query that it already contains the joins with [`contains_eager()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager):

```
session.query(Work).\
    join(Work.company_users).\
    join(CompanyUser.user).\
    options(contains_eager(Work.company_users).
            contains_eager(CompanyUser.user)).\
    filter(Work.id == 1).\
    filter(User.first_name == 'The name').\
    all()
```

Note the chained calls to `contains_eager()`.

Comment: shouldn't `outerjoin` be used instead of `join` to exactly replace `joinedload`?

Comment: @jefe23984 Yes, when the goal is to fetch also `Work` with no `User`. In this case the original query includes `filter(User.first_name == 'The name')`, so there's no need to use `outerjoin()` .

Answer (score 11):

Ok I got it. Just for those who may tackle the same issue what I did was to replace joinedload to contains_eager and added a join. Below is the revise code

```
result = (
    session.query(Work)
    .join(Work.company_users)
    .join(CompanyUser.user)
    .options(
        contains_eager(Work.company_users)
        .contains_eager(CompanyUser.user)
    )
    .filter(Work.id == 1)
    .filter(User.first_name == 'The name')  # <<--- Now this to works.
    .all()
)
```