# How to filter related object in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables, `Model`, `Parameter` and `Value` where parameters point to model and values to parameters.

What I want to do is to `filter` the parameters of some model by conditions on the parameter **and** the values and return **only** those parameters *and values* that match the criteria.
What I tried is something like:

`model.params.join(Value).filter(Param.name.in_(<whatever>), Value.type == xx, Value.count < yy)`

This returns the expected `Param` objects, however it returns **all** the `Value`s of those `Param`, including ones with, for example, `count > yy`.

What do I need to change in the query to get the result I want?

**EDIT**

This is how the relevant part of the tables looks like:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models'

    params = relationship('Param', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic', back_populates='model')

class Param(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'params'

    model = relationship('Model', back_populates='params')
    values = relationship('Value', cascade='all, delete-orphan', order_by='asc(Value.count)', back_populates='param')

class Value(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'values'

    name  = Column(String(128))
    count = Column(Integer)
    param = relationship('Param', back_populates='values')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How do you access those params and values? Are you using relationships? What do your models look like?

Comment: @IljaEverilä added the table's code. The (incomplete) query I run is in the question.

Comment: How do you use the results of that query to get at the values?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I loop over the resulting parameters, then for each loop over the values and perform an action. Currently I need to recheck the Value filters before the action which is annoying

Comment: You could use nested eager loading, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243397/sqlalchemy-joinedload-filter-column. With it the relationships are populated from the query with the filtered data.