# The unique() method must be invoked on this Result exception raised after SQLAlchemy Select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have an issue with SQLAlchemy and I cannot figure out  the cause of this error:

so my class definition is:

```
class PricingFrequency(enum.Enum):
    month = 'month'
    year = 'year'


class PlanPricing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "PlansPricing"
    pricing_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    .....
    subscription_plan = relationship("SubscriptionPlan", back_populates="plans_pricing")
    plan_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("SubscriptionPlans.plan_id"))

    created_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), server_onupdate=func.now())


class SubscriptionPlanOption(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SubscriptionPlanOptions"
    option_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    .....
    subscription_plan = relationship("SubscriptionPlan", back_populates="options_plan")
    plan_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("SubscriptionPlans.plan_id"))

    created_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), server_onupdate=func.now())


class SubscriptionPlan(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SubscriptionPlans"
    plan_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    plan_name = Column(String)
    plan_description = Column(String)
    is_popular = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    plans_pricing: List[Any] = relationship("PlanPricing", back_populates="subscription_plan")  # , lazy='joined')
    options_plan: List[Any] = relationship("SubscriptionPlanOption",
                                           back_populates="subscription_plan")  # lazy='joined')

    created_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), server_onupdate=func.now())
```

When I make this query :

```
query = (
                select(SubscriptionPlan)
                .options(joinedload(SubscriptionPlan.options_plan, innerjoin=True),
                         joinedload(SubscriptionPlan.plans_pricing.and_(PlanPricing.pricing_id == pricing_id),
                                    innerjoin=True))
            )
            items = await session.execute(query)
            items = items.scalars().all()
```

I got this error message:

```
**The unique() method must be invoked on this Result, as it contains results that include joined eager loads against collections**
```

**Note : session is  AsyncSession**

Can anyone explain the source of this issue?
Thanks

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243397/sqlalchemy-joinedload-filter-column`

Comment: Thanks. I have read this before and it does not work also with contains_eager. same error message. Not that I am using AsyncSession and not Session.

Comment: query = (
                select(SubscriptionPlan)
                .join(SubscriptionPlan.plans_pricing)
                .join(SubscriptionPlan.options_plan)
                .options(contains_eager(SubscriptionPlan.options_plan),
                         contains_eager(SubscriptionPlan.plans_pricing))
                .where(PlanPricing.pricing_id == pricing_id)
            )
            items = await session.execute(query)
            items = items.scalars().all()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The unique() method must be invoked on this Result, as it contains results that include joined eager loads against collections
```

Reason:
Quoting the documentation in
[Joined Eager Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#joined-eager-loading):

When including `joinedload()` in reference to a one-to-many or many-to-many
collection, the `Result.unique()` method must be applied to the returned result,
which will uniquify the incoming rows by primary key that otherwise are
multiplied out by the join. The ORM will raise an error if this is not present.

This is not automatic in modern SQLAlchemy, as it changes the behavior of the
result set to return fewer ORM objects than the statement would normally return
in terms of number of rows. Therefore SQLAlchemy keeps the use of
`Result.unique()` explicit, so there’s no ambiguity that the returned objects
are being uniqified on primary key.

So, you need to chain `unique()` to your `Result`:

```py
session.execute(query).unique()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to thank and add to the answer of Louis Huang (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76603245):

If we use async it is needed to chain the unique() to the awaited result.

```
statement = select(Order)
result = await session.execute(statement)
orders = result.unique().scalars().all()
```

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood sqlalchemy's loading technique. Nevertheless, my request was not well formatted, so I changed it to be that way, and it is currently functioning.

```
plan_pricing_aliased1 = aliased(PlanPricing)
plan_pricing_aliased2 = aliased(PlanPricing)
query = (
    select(
        plan_pricing_aliased1.pricing_id, 
        plan_pricing_aliased2.pricing_id
    ).join_from(
        plan_pricing_aliased1,
        plan_pricing_aliased2,
        and_(
            plan_pricing_aliased2.currency == plan_pricing_aliased1.currency,
            plan_pricing_aliased2.plan_id == plan_pricing_aliased1.plan_id,
            plan_pricing_aliased2.pricing_frequency == plan_pricing_aliased1.pricing_frequency
        )
    ).where(
        and_(
            plan_pricing_aliased1.pricing_id == pricing_id,
            plan_pricing_aliased1.price > 0,
            plan_pricing_aliased2.price == 0
        )
    )
)
items = await session.execute(query)
items = items.first()
return items
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).